# How to prevent GORM from using params from previous query

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I'm using [GORM](https://gorm.io/docs/index.html) to update 2 entities within the bounds of a db transaction:

```
tx = tx.Model(models.Action{}).Where("ID = ?", 1).UpdateColumn("state", "COMPLETE")
tx = tx.Model(models.Claim{}).Where("ID = ?", 2).Update("some_field", nil)
```

The expected rows aren't being updated, switching on logging using `db.LogMode(true)` and having a look at the SQL that GORM generates:

```
UPDATE "actions" SET "state" = 'COMPLETE'  WHERE (ID = 2) AND (ID = 1)  
UPDATE "claims" SET "some_field" = NULL  WHERE (ID = 2) AND (ID = 1) AND (ID = 2)
```

I don't understand where those additional ANDs are coming from, the only way I can get it to generate the desired queries:

```
UPDATE "actions" SET "state" = 'COMPLETE'  WHERE ID = 1
UPDATE "claims" SET "some_field" = NULL  WHERE ID = 2
```

... is to add a `New()`, so `tx.New().Model....`

Is adding New() the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you are using the old pointer that is the reason of multiple where clause.

you should try it like

```
err := tx.Model(models.Action{}).Where("ID = ?", 1).UpdateColumn("state", "COMPLETE").Error
    if err != nil {
        tx.Rollback()
    }
err = tx.Model(models.Claim{}).Where("ID = ?", 2).Update("some_field", nil).Error
    if err != nil {
        tx.Rollback()
    }
```